# How to design a unit that outputs 1 on the first rising edge and 0 on the second rising edge in the design of a multiplier?

Tags: multiplier

I want to use this unit to control the shift register in a multiplier. The shift register should load then shift and load... until it stops. When the LSB of the multiplier is 0 it should simply shift and not load. The easiest way to do  that is an AND gate. But, I need a signal that doesn't align exactly with the rising edge of the clock, in order to avoid any reading conflicts. I have a feeling that there might be an easier solution, I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Where does the title come into play in the question?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The SHIFT/LOAD line of the register should alternate between 0 and 1 for shift and load. This only happens if the select line receives a 1 on the rising edge of the CLK and 0 on the second rising edge of CLK.

Comment: How much delay do you need between the clock and the signal?

Comment: A d type flip flop sounds like it will do this. Wire D to -Q. Use clock as the input. Well that idea matches the title in the question!

Comment: Right, now it's just a matter of picking the right logic family.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Just enough so that the clock's rising edge doesnt align with the select. The select should be slightly backward.

Comment: @Andyaka Won't that make the rising edge of the  clock and the DFF's right on top of each other?

Comment: How slightly backward? 2ns? 5ns? 10ns?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Let say 5ns so that it is less than the period of a clock cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 74HC74 dual D flip-flop has a t<sub>pd</sub> from CP to Q/nQ of approximately 14ns at 5V or higher. Simply wire nQ to D and feed your clock into CP.

Comment: By any chance do you know how to implement this circuit in VHDL? I am having trouble in initializing D for the feedback to work.